# Where in Laravel 5.3 code to control content access based on published/unpublished status?

Tags: laravel

I have a guitar lessons site using Laravel 5.3. It has lessons that are then broken down into exercises.

I decided today to add in the backend the ability to mark lessons or exercises as published. I simply added a 'published' column in the respective tables which contains 0 or 1.

There are many places in my site where exercises or lessons are accessed in some shape or form, including a lesson view, exercise view, lessons partial view (a tabular listing), exercises partial view (also a tabular listing), search/query views. There are also routes that perform functions such as incrementing hit count for a lesson or exercise, adding a lesson or exercise to one's favorites.

**Given above, I am not sure how to prevent access to unpublished lessons or exercises using minimal code edits**. I started looking at the controller files but then realized the controller might not be a catch all, such as on query result pages. Also controller files contain multiple methods and I don't want to edit them separately. I suspect there is a "laravel way" to do what I need globally, without me having to modify a bunch of queries in multiple files. **Maybe it amounts to middleware or something?**

In any case, I am new to laravel and if there is a tried and true way to control routes for content that is marked as unpublished, I would be very interested to know about it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes), laravelest way to do this

Comment: That is really slick! Tried it out and works nicely. But now I am not seeing the unpublished items in my backend CRUD... So I added this in the boot method: if (!$user->hasRole('admin')) and all seems well. Will need to test more, but thanks for showing me this!

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I prefer to use timestamps for things like published states on models. It means I can set a future timestamp for that content to become available, i.e. if I’m going on holiday.

In terms of your actual problem, a query scope would be the way to go:

```php
class Lesson extends Model
{
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->wherePublished(true);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you did use a timestamp instead, you could do:

```php
class Lesson extends Model
{
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published', '<=', $this->freshTimestamp());
    }
}
```

You will then need to update your front-end code to use this scope:

```php
public function LessonController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $lessons = Lesson::published()->latest()->paginate();

        return view('lesson.index', compact('lessons'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. In LessonController by published() I take it you mean scopePublished()? In my current Lesson controller I have this line: $query = \App\Lesson::query(); With your approach would I just change it to how you have above? What about the fact that the Lesson controller has other methods? I am trying to figure out way to apply one check to published status and have it work across all relevant methods.

Comment: Even though the method’s defined as `scopePublished()` in the model, you would just called `published()` in your client code—Laravel will automatically figure out you mean the scope method. Counter-intuitive, I know!

Comment: I see how your answer in essence relates to the idea of scopes that @Quezler mentioned. I seem to hjave things working now using a global scope and testing for whether user is admin. Learn something new about laravel every day! But need to get back to playing guitar!

Comment: I wouldn’t check the user in global scope if that’s what you’re doing, as it’ll make your models unusable in say, the command line (where there’s no notion of user authentication). You’re probably best doing something like `Lesson::withoutGlobalScope(PublishedScope::class)->get()` in your admin panel to get un-published lessons.

Comment: Ok, I will have to read up on scope classes to better understand how to implement in that way. regards